# Is XDocument appropriate for generating HTML?

Tags: html, wcf, linq-to-xml, dynamically-generated

My goal is to use a WCF Service to accept some parameters, generate and then return a HTML string that a user can use to embed on certain webpages of their choice.

**Is XDocument appropriate for generating a string of HTML?**

I do not really need a full HTML document, just a simple snippet that has some image elements, a p-tag element, and a table element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's suitable for *generating* XHTML, which is valid XML. It wouldn't be suitable for *parsing* HTML, which doesn't have to be a valid XML document.

There may be more HTML-specific APIs available, but for just a simple snippet of XHTML, using `XDocument` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did a proof of concept and it worked great! thanks!